# Google maps Autocomplete: output only address without country and city

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I use [Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) to autocomplete address input. Search is limited to only one city, and I get output like this:

"Rossiya, Moskva, Leninskiy prospekt 28"

How to hide "Rossiya, Moskva"? ...

My query:

```
function() {
        // Search bounds
        var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.686534, 35.463867);
        var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(56.926993, 39.506836);
        self.options = {
            bounds : new google.maps.LatLngBounds(p1, p2),
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'ru'},
        };

        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.address');

        for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elements[i],
                    self.options);
        }
```

Comment: The docs here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places say the following, try it `vicinity: A simplified address for the Place, including the street name, street number, and locality, but not the province/state, postal code, or country. For example, Google's Sydney, Australia office has a vicinity value of 5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont.`

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but vicinity is Place property and in my case  autocomplete.getPlace() return undefined. Could not yet find solution.

Comment: You can extrapolate from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671434/is-there-any-way-to-customize-googles-auto-complete-address-result/49672234) to build your own autocomplete widget with exactly the information you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can but you have to replace the value of the input field in two places.

Example:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, placesOptions);
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
```

inside the 'place_changed' event you need to do the following:

```
placeResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
//This will get only the address
input.value = placeResult.name;
```

This will change the value in the searchtextfield to the street address.

The second place is a bit tricky:

```
input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
// timeoutfunction allows to force the autocomplete field to only display the street name.
if(placeResult){ setTimeout(function(){ input.value = placeResult.name; }, 1); } });
```

The reason why we have to do this is because if you only add the event listener for blur, google places will populate the input field with the full address, so you have to 'wait' for google to update and then force your change by waiting some miliseconds.

Try it without the setTimeout function and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You can't.  I had it the other way around, that you were just looking for a city.  There is no way to only print out the street name (I'm assuming that's a street name) from the address component.

---

**OPPOSITE OF WHAT WAS ASKED**

[From the docs:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete)

> the (cities) type collection instructs the Place service to return results that match either `locality` or `administrative_area3`.

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['(cities)']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Comment: Love firm answers that say "You can't" ... Worst thing, this answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

in result u have hash and from it u can get part what u want:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

now from "place" u can get it

```
place.geometry.location.lat()
```

and for address

```
place.address_components[0] or place.address_components[1] ...
```

depends on what u want to get

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem which indeed was solvable. This in an Angular 2 project but it should be applicable elsewhere as well. I filter my results for establishments, and wanted to show only the name and hide the address part of the result. This did the trick for me, a function executing once you select a suggestion:

```
   getAddress(place: Object) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.establishment = place['name'];
    });
```

where `zone` is an NgZone component injected in the constructor and `this.establishment` is the variable tied to `[(NgModel)]` in the input field.

Answer (score -1):

Inside place_changed set a timeout function:

```
var streetString = place.address_components[0] or place.address_components[1];

window.setTimeout(function() {
  $('input').val(streetString);
}, 200);
```

This solution worked for me.