# Autocomplete on google map API should return only cities

Tags: google-maps

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAiv004_zrkpEL-v1u-LU6QYIkgv7yjT_M&language={{ Lang::getLocale() }}&libraries=places&" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {

        var options = {
          types: ['(cities)']
        };

        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('location'));

        var inputLat = $("input[name*='lat']");
        var inputLng = $("input[name*='lng']");
        var inputPlaceId = $("input[name*='place_id']");

        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = places.getPlace();
            var address = place.formatted_address;
            var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
            var placeId = place.place_id;

            inputLat.val(latitude);
            inputLng.val(longitude);
            inputPlaceId.val(placeId);
        });
    });


    $('#location').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
          google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
          return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I need it to display only cities, but somehow I get countries too.. I don't want to display continents and countries. please help

Answer (score 1):

If you check the autocomplete [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete), it is stated here that:

> the `(cities)` type collection instructs the Places service to return
>   results that match either locality or administrative_area3

So like you have done, you need the cities as types parameter.

What you can do is to specify the country in the Google API call with a help of region parameter. Just check this [tutorial](http://rustamagasanov.com/blog/2014/09/04/google-places-limit-autocomplete-results-to-cities-only/) on how to do that.

Here is the sample request:

```
= javascript_include_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&sensor=false&libraries=places&region=UK"
```

For more information, check this related SO question it may give you an idea on how to solve this issue.

- [Google maps Autocomplete: output only address without country and city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125189/google-maps-autocomplete-output-only-address-without-country-and-city)
- [Is there a way to get only the city name from Google Places API instead of getting the whole location?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-get-only-the-city-name-from-Google-Places-API-instead-of-getting-the-whole-location)