# Google Maps API Autocomplete - How to output only the Streetname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a input field, where only addresses return.

But when i enter a streetname, the input field return the streetname plus a comma and the city of the street.

I got following code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=de&language=de&sensor=false"></script>
<input id="strasse" type="text" size="50">

 $(function(){     

    var input = document.getElementById('strasse');         
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
        types: ["address"]
    });          

    $("#strasse").focusin(function () {
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                infowindow.close();

            }
        });
    });
});
```

EG:

I enter "Teststreet"
Output = "Teststreet, Munich"

The return should only be "Teststreet".

Is there a way, to delete everything after the "," (maybe over jQuery)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125189/google-maps-autocomplete-output-only-address-without-country-and-city

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps Autocomplete: output only address without country and city](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125189/google-maps-autocomplete-output-only-address-without-country-and-city)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `place_changed` event listener and then choose what you want from what is returned:

```
    <script>
    var input = document.getElementById('strasse');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
            types: ["address"]
        });     
     $(function(){     

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

        $("#strasse").focusin(function () {
            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    infowindow.close();

                }
            });
        });
    });

    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (typeof place.address_components[0] !== "undefined") {
            $(input).val(place.address_components[0].long_name);
        }
    }
     </script>
```

There is also quite a nice demo of what can be achieved [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-autocomplete-addressform).

In this instance we are using `long_name` of the `route` type that is returned. Simply `console_log(place.address_components);` to see the full list that is returned.

Comment: Thank you! This was what i've looking for.