# Custom Address for Google Autocomplete Search Box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, location, google-places-api

I have an autocomplete (Places Autocomplete by Google) on my website that works fine and is restricted to the boundaries I have. But there are some locations that are missing when somebody types it in the search box, even though these locations do exist on the actual Google Maps. The javascript implementation for the Autocomplete is below.

```
function initAutocomplete(){
      var areaboundary = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(51.377809, -3.508688),
          new google.maps.LatLng(51.628119, -2.954925)
      );


  var options = {
    bounds: areaboundary,
    strictBounds: true,
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}
  };
  var input = document.getElementById('property-location');
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);



  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if(place.length === 0){
      return;
    }

    if(place.formatted_address == "Cardiff, UK"){
      jQuery("#property-radius-sale option[value=5]").prop("selected", true);
      jQuery("#property-radius-rent option[value=5]").prop("selected", true);
    }

    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
    var coordinates = [lat, lng];

    var hidden_input = document.getElementById("lat-lng-location");
    hidden_input.value = coordinates;
  });
}
```

The location I am trying to add is this one:

[Location to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKuWk.png)

The reason why I need this specific address is because the addresses the come up on the website do include Cardiff Bay as well.

My question is, how can one add a custom address/location with the lng and lat to the Places Autocomplete?

Comment: Why are they not showing? Any example? How did you implement the Autocomplete? Might be worth trying to figure out why some places don't show in your implementation before trying to hack the behavior of the widget. That said if you really need to, this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671434/is-there-any-way-to-customize-googles-auto-complete-address-result). And please take the [tour] and read on [ask] to improve your question and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: My bad in that regard. Everything was implemented as explained in the examples shown on the Autocomplete documentation. I have an autocomplete object initialized with a strict area boundary (I made sure the location that is missing is within the lat long boundaries). The autocomplete has a listener that gets the Place and assigns the lat long value from the Google response to a hidden field.
An example would be the location: "Cardiff Bay. It exists on Google Maps and is a big location, but doesn't come up in the autocomplete. I've tried removing the boundary, but still not showing.

Comment: Thank you for the link with the answered question. I have also updated my question so it is more detailed in regards to what problem I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue you have with `Cardiff Bay, UK` is caused by the `types` parameter. The place is considered as a *natural feature* and is not returned by the API if you specify the `geocode` type.

It will be listed though if you don't specify a type, or use `types: ['geocode', 'establishment']` which [according to the docs](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3) is identical to specifying no type.

```js
function initialize() {

  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'uk'
      }
    });

  ac.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    var place = ac.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    var html = '<div>Latitude: ' + place.geometry.location.lat() + '</div>';
    html += '<div>Longitude: ' + place.geometry.location.lng() + '</div>';

    document.getElementById('geometry').innerHTML = html;
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 10px;
}

#autocomplete {
  width: 400px;
}

#geometry {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="autocomplete" value="Cardiff Bay" type="text">
<div id="geometry">

</div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This solution was exactly what I was looking for!