# Angular JavaScript AutoComplete Cant Find Address Field (Add Custom Fields to AutoComplete)

Tags: javascript, angular, google-places-api

I am making a little component for an app I am working on using the Google Places API and am looking to be pointed in the right direction in terms of manipulating the DOM to add a custom field above the 5 options on the Google Places AutoComplete API.

I do not think making a directive is an option here because I only have the input field for the feature. I am open to other tricks.

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-places-autocomplete for the Places API and I got everything working, but for some reason, I cannot in the life of me build the solution for adding a custom field prepended above the 5 address options on the prefill.

Anyone else dealing with this?

Comment: Any modification of the Places Autocomplete widget *will* be some sort of hack. If you want full control over the way it looks and behaves, use the [Places Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) instead.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there any way to customize Google's Auto complete address result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671434/is-there-any-way-to-customize-googles-auto-complete-address-result)