# Style Vue2-Google-maps autocomplete like vuetify v-text-field

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm wondering what the best way to style the gmap-autocomplete field like a vuetify v-text-field.
I've looked at Vuetify-google-autocomplete module but it's throwing lots of errors and being more or an issue than i expected.

Whats the easiest way to make

```
<gmap-autocomplete></gmap-autocomplete>
```

Look like

```
<v-text-field></v-text-field>
```

without changing functionality

Comment: You can use the [Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) and build your own widget and thus control the look, functionality and behavior.

Comment: @MrUpsidown could you point me in the direction of some resources to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671434/is-there-any-way-to-customize-googles-auto-complete-address-result

Comment: https://medium.com/@siddhartharora02/places-autocomplete-service-by-google-maps-api-vue-js-js-client-side-202b7fd7baf0

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a google address autocomplete with vue and vuetify.

You need to use "v-autocomplete" instead of "v-text-field". Its a vuetify component too

I will share some code about my implementation with the basics (my component is more complex)

Keep in mind to put your APIKEY in the URL

Also, In my implementation, I have added debounce library for add some delay in the autocomplete, I can add the code with this feature if you wish

**CODE:**

```
<template>
    <v-autocomplete
            prepend-icon="account_box"
            v-model="address"
            :items="items"
            name="address"
            :search-input.sync="search"
            label="Address"
            placeholder="Address"
            class="pa-3"
            autocomplete="off"
            :loading="loading"
            :filter="d=>d"
            color="secondary"
            item-color="secondary"
            return-object
            @change="change"
    ></v-autocomplete>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                items: [],
                search: null,
                address: null
            }
        },
        watch: {
            search(){
                //Optional: here you can add some delay
                this.googleSearch()
            }
        },
        methods: {
            googleSearch() {
                let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={YOURAPIKEY}&address='
                fetch(url + this.address)
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json()
                    })
                    .then(jsonResult => {
                        this.items = jsonResult.map(item => {
                            //You can explore and use other information inside "item" like latitude, longitude, country, City, zipCode
                            return {
                                text: item.formatted_address,
                                value: item.formatted_address
                            }
                        })
                    }).catch(err => { 
                        //handle errors 
                        console.log(err)
                     })
                        
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't make use of the Google Places API [Autocomplete widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete) like what OP is using, nor does it implement the [Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) but instead sends the input to the Geocoder service, which is billed at a higher rate and is really not adequate for a *Places* autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, worked for me:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-google-autocomplete

```
npm i vuetify-google-autocomplete
```

I needed to bind "id" to something unique in order to have multiple instances of the field on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

while not using the exact same thing I found out that I had to globally style the element to what I wanted it to be.

The below code is what I used:

```
<style global>
#vuetify-google-autocomplete-id {
border-top-width: 0px !important;
border-right-width: 0px !important;
border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
border-left-width: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

I hope it can help anyone who is looking for a solution.