# How to fire a click/change event for a custom address with google place autocomplete address in angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-autocomplete

I am using google place autocomplete and it's working fine. But I need to add some custom addresses from DB. I did it by custom HTML by catching google place autocomplete CSS class name like (.pac-container).
[image]

```js
@ViewChild('addressSearch') addresstext!: ElementRef;

  chnageAddress(event: any) {
    this.aa = (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.pac-container'));
    let item = '<div class="pac-item"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched">Local Address </span>1</span><span></span></div>';
    item += '<div class="pac-item"><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched">Local Address </span>2</span><span></span></div>';
    this.aa.innerHTML = item;

    (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.pac-item')).addEventListener('click',
      this.showMap.bind(this));
  }

  showMap() {
    alert('action from custom place');
  }

  getPlaceAutocomplete() {
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.addresstext.nativeElement,
      {
        types: ['establishment', 'geocode']
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
      this.ref.detach();

      setInterval(() => { this.ref.detectChanges(); }, 200);

    });
  }
```

```html
 <div class="input-group">
                          <input (input)="chnageAddress($event);" formControlName="addressSearch" type="text"
                            placeholder="search address" #addressSearch id="addressSearch" class="form-control"
                            leftTrim>
                          <span class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="icon-target"></i>
                          </span>
                          <img src="assets/images/pwb-google-maps.svg" alt="" class="powered-by-logo">
                        </div>
```

Now the problem is custom event not fired for my custom address. I have tried in different ways.
[image]

Note: Google place autocomplete default change event working only for goole address not custom address.
[image]

Someone tell me where is my wrong and who to solve, Thanks to all.

Comment: you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49672234/4960765

Comment: I need typescript solution, but its js and jquery solution. thanks for your answer @Jimmy

Comment: @Jimmy, Can you provide a solutions for TypeScript and Angular?